# Can you change and deploy an Apex Class in MavensMate without compiling against the source server?

Tags: apex, mavensmate, sublime

I use MavensMate to deploy apps to many different orgs that have one particular apex class that must be distinct in each org. Our TriggerFactory.cls contains object references specific to that Org's logic and so I must merge my template version of TriggerFactory.cls into each Org's TriggerFactory.cls

I know that I can choose to save locally with MavensMate and skip having the file compiled against its source server, but I do not know whether that version will be maintained when I prepare a deploy package to send to another Org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it pulls the files from the source org first and then deploys. I once tried deploying a class that someone else had modified, but I hadn't updated in MavensMate. It deployed the version from Salesforce instead of the one locally.

Comment: Yup, that's what my experiments have shown too. Even when the local file is saved without compiling against the source it still pulls from the source at run time when you start the deploy.

I suppose I can take advantage of the nicely built package.xml and just switch over to the CLI and deploy with Ant directly.

Comment: My other thought on an approach is to use a sandbox as a feature branch and metadata source where I can merge and compile the unique file.

Comment: I often switch to Ant to deploy after building my package with MavensMate.